# Dynamically Change Pulumi Aws Az For multiple EC2 in same python file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pulumi

```py
server = aws.ec2.Instance(
   'rumbleInstance2',
   instance_type=size,
   vpc_security_group_ids=[group.id],
   region="Whateever region i want"
)
```

Some option that i can think of are overloading provider function (i am not sure if i am doing it right)

Comment: It's not super obvious what you're asking here, but I think Transformations is what you want?

https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/resources/options/transformations/

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pulumi_aws as aws

available = aws.get_availability_zones(state="available")
primary = aws.ec2.Subnet("primary", availability_zone=available.names[0])

server = aws.ec2.Instance(
   'rumbleInstance2',
   instance_type=size,
   vpc_security_group_ids=[group.id],
   region="Whateever region i want",
   availabilityZone=primary 
)
```